# "One of the best language" vs "One of the best languages"

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is the correct sentence?

> Tamil is one of **the oldest *language*.**

or

> Tamil is one of **the oldest *languages***

  -

Comment: If you say "one of" you imply that there is a "number" of things you are referring to. In this case you are referring to "languages" among which Tamil is the oldest. – xxxxxx 18 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

As @xxxxxx stated, using "one of" implies that there are multiple items (old languages in this case). In your example, Tamil is one of the set of multiple old languages.

> Tamil is one of the oldest languages.

would be the correct sentence, since you're pointing out one item of a set (of multiple old languages). You may also say

> Tamil is the oldest language.

If Tamil is indeed the oldest language of the set, and there is no older language.